# How to fix 'not support yet' error Cassandra run in Azure service?

Tags: azure, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Azure Cosmos DB Cassandra, I receive an error when excuse queries contain specials key, such as MAX, ALLOW FILTERING, etc...Database azure response message did not support for.

> ServerError: ALLOW FILTERING queries are not supported yet for the
>   query provided.
>       ServerError: 'MAX' is not supported yet.

With query simple below I get the same error.

```
 create table Test(id uuid, value decimal, primary key(id, value));
```

Error:

> ServerError: Type decimal for column value is not supported as a
>   cluster key yet.
>
> version: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native
>   protocol v4

Comment: I'd suggest submitting your requests to UserVoice or open a discussion on an Azure-specific support forum. There's nothing you can fix: the Cassandra API does not implement 100% of Cassandra's features.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a product support / feature request. Not a specific programming issue that can be resolved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack overflow and Azure!

**Note:** Allow filtering, and max operation is currently not supported in Azure Cosmos DB Cassandra API.

For more details, refer “[Apache Cassandra features supported by Azure Cosmos DB Cassandra API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support)”.

I would suggest you to provide feedback here:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.